# What is the advantage of using L*a*b in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, color-spaces

In a couple posts, I noticed throw-away remarks about using Lab as the recommended or only serious thing to do.

Why?

Answer (score 6):

`Lab` is one of those colour spaces that people are either 'in the know' and use when it's appropriate or they just see as a bit of a scary place to be avoided.  It's not a one-size fits all space and it takes some getting used to.

The main reason to use Lab in a professional setting is that, once you get a handle on it, having Luminosity and Colour kept separate enables a very quick workflow as often the reasons for going to Lab are to do things you can do in RGB but in a fraction of the time.  It's also great for making colours pop without them making a bee-line for the primaries.  And it is a godsend when you have a washed out or tired looking original as you can make some quite bold increases in colour before things start looking unnatural.

It has a few other tricks up it's sleeve too especially when it comes to colour replacement.  You can really pull some colour replacement tricks without having to do intricate masks too once you get used to it.

Definitely have a search around for videos featuring [Dan Margulis](http://www.moderncolorworkflow.com/dan-margulis) as well as reading "The" book (Photoshop LAB Color - The Canyon Conundrum and Other Adventures in the Most Powerful Colorspace.)

Answer (score 1):

For doing a perfect color correction without change the luminosity:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhfRynutmQM

read about from a guru of LAB Color space:

http://www.moderncolorworkflow.com/dan-margulis

Comment: Why not work in XYZ space?

Answer (score 0):

@jdlugosz - There are a couple of items - it's a big color space and for me, the key reason, is that I can adjust the colors / saturation without effecting the brightness.

Comment: Same question as above: Why not work in XYZ space?

Comment: @CountIblis this question is about Lab, if you want to know the difference between XYZ and Lab then that would be a good question to ask.